# USB interface barcode scanners

Tags: keyboard, usb, barcode, barcode-scanner, wedge

Not exactly a programming question, but close. I'll try my luck anyway.

> The **keyboard wedge
>   barcode scanner** inserts the
>   translation device between the reader
>   and the keyboard. **Data sent through a
>   wedge appears as if it was typed into
>   the computer, while the keyboard
>   itself remains fully functional**.
>   Because a computer using a keyboard
>   wedge can't tell the difference
>   between data that is entered by a
>   scanning device, or data that is
>   entered by keyboard typing, *a wedge
>   can be used to easily add barcode
>   reading capability to an existing
>   computer without modifying software
>   applications*.

I'd like to know if all USB interface barcode scanners automatically translate digital signals from a barcode reader into keyboard strokes for a applications just like wedge or is USB different from wedge?

Many thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are all sorts of API to access barcode scanners -- by no means do they all work by making believe they're "the keyboard"!-)  For example, [here](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-scanners/integration-guide.html) you can find a reasonable summary of possibilities (the classic rs232 approach, the "wedge" one, and USB-interface ones) albeit for a single firm producing them.  Depending on what programming you're willing and able to do, your best choice might be any of these approaches, or others yet.

Comment: The application is already developed with wedge (keyboard-like) input in mind, like your fellow co-worker (Matt Cutts) shows in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q95ywcuGuTM :) 

I'm just not sure if its the wedge or USB scanner I want.

Comment: The one he's using is also USB, so I wonder if all USB scanners provide keyboard-like input?

Comment: @Nimbuz, while most USB scanners no doubt do provide at least one mode where they can emulate a/the keyboard, I wouldn't take it for granted that such a software mode "must certainly be" present just because the HW interface is USB -- rather, I'd check the spec sheet for the specific scanner brand and model to ascertain that it is.

Comment: +1 the readers I've dealt with usually have both, since you don't always want keyboard-emulation. I remember the last one I used was really cool in that you put it in keyboard mode by reading a special barcode. Very nice, but sorry but I don't remember the name.

Comment: +1 I have integrated with a variety of scanners .. if you want one that performs this way, another term you should look also for the term "HID" mode - Human Interface Device (aka Keyboard Wedge).  Bluetooth scanners also may or may not support HID/Wedge mode.