# Can web application handles devices?

Tags: php, system, erp

I hope to develop web based ERP system for retail startup. Is that possible to configure a device like bar-code reader? It runs through the browser. Will the browser can identify that kind of device?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question but yes, many barcode readers connect and interact with a device as a simple keyboard.  If, in your webapp you provide an input with focus and then scan a barcode, many will act the same as if you had typed the number in yourself.  See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892280/usb-interface-barcode-scanners)

Comment: They make usb barcode readers that act as a keyboard, so as long as your web based system puts the focus on the right field, the barcode scanner puts the code into the field.  I bought 8 x $12 scanners on amazon to get this working on all of our POS.  I also use zxing for their mobile fulfillment, it works with the zxing android app, so when they click a link to scan a code it opens the app, and then the app sends the browser to a custom url with the barcode embedded in a variable.  It was full barcode functionality we needed in under an hour of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage wouldn't have access to controlling how the client system deals with its hardware, but if configured *normally* on the client, the barcode reader will act just like a keyboard, and keyboards can indeed send information to a browser.

Although most punch clocks are simpler (cheaper) devices than a full computer with browser and everything, it can certainly be done that way.